# Fade Image whenever I click a button

Tags: css, unity-game-engine

Im making a game and I have a main menu with a start button that works perfectly fine. The only problem is you can see the background so I added another image called 'fadeImage' and I want to have it so whenever the function that is responsible for detecting whenever I click, will fade the image called 'fadeImage'. I tried using GetComponent and GetGameObject and whenever I use CrossFade Alpha I get the error `Object reference not set to instance of object` on line 51.
Heres my code

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class StartOptions : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int sceneToStart = 1;                                        //Index number in build settings of scene to load if changeScenes is true
    public bool changeScenes;                                           //If true, load a new scene when Start is pressed, if false, fade out UI and continue in single scene
    public bool changeMusicOnStart;                                     //Choose whether to continue playing menu music or start a new music clip
    public Image fadeImage;

    [HideInInspector] public bool inMainMenu = true;                    //If true, pause button disabled in main menu (Cancel in input manager, default escape key)
    [HideInInspector] public Animator animColorFade;                    //Reference to animator which will fade to and from black when starting game.
    [HideInInspector] public Animator animMenuAlpha;                    //Reference to animator that will fade out alpha of MenuPanel canvas group
     public AnimationClip fadeColorAnimationClip;       //Animation clip fading to color (black default) when changing scenes
    [HideInInspector] public AnimationClip fadeAlphaAnimationClip;      //Animation clip fading out UI elements alpha

    private PlayMusic playMusic;                                        //Reference to PlayMusic script
    private float fastFadeIn = .01f;                                    //Very short fade time (10 milliseconds) to start playing music immediately without a click/glitch
    private ShowPanels showPanels;                                      //Reference to ShowPanels script on UI GameObject, to show and hide panels

    void Awake()
    {
        //Get a reference to ShowPanels attached to UI object
        showPanels = GetComponent<ShowPanels> ();

        //Get a reference to PlayMusic attached to UI object
        playMusic = GetComponent<PlayMusic> ();

        fadeImage = GetComponent<Image>();       
    }

    public void StartButtonClicked()
    {
        //If changeMusicOnStart is true, fade out volume of music group of AudioMixer by calling FadeDown function of PlayMusic, using length of fadeColorAnimationClip as time. 
        //To change fade time, change length of animation "FadeToColor"
        fadeImage.CrossFadeAlpha(1.0f, 1.0f, true);

        if (changeMusicOnStart) 
        {
            playMusic.FadeDown(fadeColorAnimationClip.length);
        }

        //If changeScenes is true, start fading and change scenes halfway through animation when screen is blocked by FadeImage
        if (changeScenes) 
        {
            //Use invoke to delay calling of LoadDelayed by half the length of fadeColorAnimationClip
            Invoke ("LoadDelayed", fadeColorAnimationClip.length * .5f);

            //Set the trigger of Animator animColorFade to start transition to the FadeToOpaque state.
            animColorFade.SetTrigger ("fade");
        } 

        //If changeScenes is false, call StartGameInScene
        else 
        {
            //Call the StartGameInScene function to start game without loading a new scene.
            StartGameInScene();
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneWasLoaded;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= SceneWasLoaded;
    }

    //Once the level has loaded, check if we want to call PlayLevelMusic
    void SceneWasLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        //if changeMusicOnStart is true, call the PlayLevelMusic function of playMusic
        if (changeMusicOnStart)
        {
            playMusic.PlayLevelMusic ();
        }   
    }

    public void LoadDelayed()
    {
        //Pause button now works if escape is pressed since we are no longer in Main menu.
        inMainMenu = false;

        //Hide the main menu UI element
        showPanels.HideMenu ();

        //Load the selected scene, by scene index number in build settings
        SceneManager.LoadScene (sceneToStart);
    }

    public void HideDelayed()
    {
        //Hide the main menu UI element after fading out menu for start game in scene
        showPanels.HideMenu();
    }

    public void StartGameInScene()
    {
        //Pause button now works if escape is pressed since we are no longer in Main menu.
        inMainMenu = false;

        //If changeMusicOnStart is true, fade out volume of music group of AudioMixer by calling FadeDown function of PlayMusic, using length of fadeColorAnimationClip as time. 
        //To change fade time, change length of animation "FadeToColor"
        if (changeMusicOnStart) 
        {
            //Wait until game has started, then play new music
            Invoke ("PlayNewMusic", fadeAlphaAnimationClip.length);
        }
        //Set trigger for animator to start animation fading out Menu UI
        animMenuAlpha.SetTrigger ("fade");
        Invoke("HideDelayed", fadeAlphaAnimationClip.length);
        Debug.Log ("Game started in same scene! Put your game starting stuff here.");
    }

    public void PlayNewMusic()
    {
        //Fade up music nearly instantly without a click 
        playMusic.FadeUp (fastFadeIn);
        //Play music clip assigned to mainMusic in PlayMusic script
        playMusic.PlaySelectedMusic (1);
    }
}
```

The start button works whenever I remove any code referencing to the image , but when I dont I get the error and the Start button just stays blue, which is supposed to happen only when you're mouse is over it.

Comment: it seems that simply `fadeImage` is not referenced. => There is no component `Image` on that GameObject.

Comment: @derHugo I added an image called fadeImage into the button where the script is. I replaced the script with the one I posted and I still get the same errors

Answer (score 0):

This line `fadeImage = GetComponent<Image>();` in your `Start` function would only work if you attach this script to your image. That is why you are getting a null reference error because object which has this monobehavior has no Image component.

Comment: This `fadeImage.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();` makes no sense at all... You either already have the `fadeImage` reference than you don't need to get it again. Or you do not have the reference in which case it will throw a `NullReferenceException` at `.gameObject` anyway...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
fadeImage = GetComponent<Image>();
```

simply fails and returns `null` since there is no `Image` component on exactly that `GameObject` this script is attached to.

> [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) Returns the component of Type type if the game object has one attached, null if it doesn't.

---

You say

> I added an image called fadeImage **into** the button

so I'ld say you rather want to use [`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html) to look for that `Image` component recursive in the hierarchy **under** the `GameObject` this script is attached to

```
// By passing a true as parameter you make also
// Sure that the component will also be found
// if it is currently not active or disabled - otherwise it would be ignored
fadeImage = GetComponentInChildren<Image>(true);
```

Comment: it used to give me an error whenever I clicked the start button and it wouldnt fade, but now it does but the fadeImage still wont do anything

Comment: So the `NullReferenceException` seems to be solved than. I see however you also have some animators .. is it possible that somewhere in those animators a keyframe was set for the Image's alpha? If so the animator will overrule any changes made by script!